# How to format a list containing tags in python

Tags: python

I have a list called tokens and would like to format this list so that when I print it, it is human readable.

The list:

```
tokens = ['<h1>','Hello','World','</h1>','<p>','Welcome','to','this','planet','</p>']
```

What I would like the output to look like once formatted:

> Heading: Hello World
>
> Paragraph: Welcome to this planet

What I have tried so far:

I have first tried to replace the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags so that when output it shows 'Heading: ' and 'Paragraph: ' instead. I used a FOR loop to loop through all the tokens and find the correct tags to replace:

```
for token in tokens:
# comparing strings
elif token == '<h1>':
   print(token.replace('<h1>', 'Heading: '))
elif token == '<p>':
   print(token.replace('<p>', 'Paragraph: '))
```

The next part I need to do is print out the sentences between the `<h1>` tags and the `<p>` tags. For this I thought of creating a method, the general pseudo code is:

```
def between(tokens, tag, endTag)
    if token is between tag and endTag
        print the sentence
```

I don't really know how to get this method to work in python and have tried something like this:

```
def between(tokens, tag, endTag):
sentence = []
for token in tokens:
    if(token > tag and token < endTag):
        sentance.append(token)
return sentance
```

but I know the if statement does not make sense and does not work out overall. How can I solve this problem and format the list correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of human-readable tag names and replace a tag with its name. If a token is not a tag, it is not replaced.

```
tags = {"<h1>" : 'Heading1: ', "</h1>" : "\n", 
        "<p>" : "Paragraph: ", "</p>" : "\n", ... }
new_tokens = [tags.get(token.lower(),token) for token in tokens]
print("".join(new_tokens))
#Heading1: HelloWorld
#Paragraph: Welcometothisplanet
```

The `.lower()` function call makes the lookup case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you this method is much easier to do/understand than the method I was originally planning

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
" ".join('@#'.join([e for e in tokens if '</' not in e]).replace("<h1>","\n Heading:").replace("<p>","\n Paragraph:").split("@#"))
```

Given that your string doesn't have a @#.